# Is there any way to control the index of an element in a list while I am doing a fold?

Tags: list, haskell, fold, polynomials

Im trying to make some functions and methods for a Haskell type called "Polynomial" which represents a mathematical polynomial. This type is defined as follows:

```
data Pol = Nil | P Grade Coefficient (Pol) deriving Show
```

So, for example the polynomial x^3 + 2x^2 + 8 would be represented as

```
P 3 1 (P 2 2 (P 0 8 Nil))
```

There is a function called "list2Pol" which should get a lista *[Integer]* and transform it into a Polynomial, where the index of that list represent the grade of that coefficient. So, for example:

```
list2Pol [6,1,0,3] = P 3 3 (P 1 1 (P 0 6 Nil)
```

However, it seems easy to implement without folds, but I would like to know how to implement it by folding, because my code which is down doesnt work

```
list2Pol :: [Integer] -> Pol
list2Pol [] = Nil
list2Pol l = foldl (\x solResto -> insert (length l) x solResto) Nil l
```

I would apreciate you to help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can first `zip` your list with the list `[0..]` and then use that as the index:

```hs
list2Pol l = foldr (\(i,x) rest -> insert i x rest) Nil (zip [0..] l)
```

Note that in this case you want to use `foldr` and not `foldl` and the `[]` case is redundant, the fold will take care of that case automatically.

Comment: you are right, thanks. However, for the example [6,1,0,3] given in the post it says an exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function insert

Comment: @j.j.3 then there is probably a problem in your insert function.